# Which external GPS logger for a Panasonic Lumix G9?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, panasonic-lumix, geotagging, gps

Which **external GPS logger** can I connect to the Panasonic **Lumix G9** for real time geotagging **without a smartphone**?

With external GPS logger, I mean devices like

- Qstarz GPS BT-Q1000XT
- TSI GL-770
- ...

Currently I use a Garmin GPSMap to track the position and tag the photos offline while post processing the exif tags with Digikam and similar tools on Linux.

Is there a specific protocol which the GPS logger needs to support?

Comment: When you say "connect", do you mean via USB, or Bluetooth, or...? Also, do you have reason to believe the G9 supports external GPS loggers without a smartphone? The G9 manual doesn't mention "GPS", and none of the references to "USB" mention anything except for charging or PC sync.

Comment: @scottbb I've read about GPS, geotagging and Bluetooth for the G9 and for GPS devices an expected that there is a link. Now I realize that it might be impossible...